# hey can anyone tell me about why im not rendering the data from api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, reactjs, axios

im new in react so please give me the solution for below problem

im creating api where user can add image and select the radio btn and send data to api get the revelwnt data of image but in if condition axios display error in cosole i.e axios is not defined due to this im not able to map the data from api so any one tell me where is wrong method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Image extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { file: '', imagePreviewUrl: '' , change: [],  path:"false"};
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // TODO: do something with -> this.state.file
        const byteCode = this.state.imagePreviewUrl
        var byteCode = this.state.imagePreviewUrl.substring(0, 30, e.target.value.indexOf(''));
        // substring used for remove "data:image/png;base64," from img src tag on line no 56 to pass base64 value to api
        debugger;

        var byteCode = this.state.imagePreviewUrl.substring((e.target.value).indexOf(',') + 23);
        console.log('base64 byte code substring data', byteCode);
        const valueRadio = this.state.selectedOption

        console.log(valueRadio)
        if (valueRadio == "celeb") {
            let url = "http://192.168.4.138/MediaAnalysisImage_Amazon/api/IdentifyCelebrity/IdentifyCelebrity"
            console.log(url);
            const data = { "isFilePath":this.state.path, "fileByte": byteCode}


            console.log(data)

            const response = axios.post(url, data)
                .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    change: response.data
                });
            })
        }


    }
    celebData() {

        return (this.state.change).map((celebrity) => {
            const filebyte = celebrity.fileByte
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{filebyte}</p>
                </div>
                )
        })
    }
    radioChange=(e)=> {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: e.target.value

        });

    }
    handleImageChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];


        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                file: file,
                imagePreviewUrl: reader.result


            });

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    }

    render() {
        let { imagePreviewUrl } = this.state;

        let $imagePreview = null;
        if (imagePreviewUrl) {
            $imagePreview = (<img src={imagePreviewUrl}   width="20%" />);
            console.log(imagePreviewUrl)
        } else {
            $imagePreview = (<span className="previewText">Please select an Image for Preview</span>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="face" onChange={this.radioChange}/>Face
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="celeb" onChange={this.radioChange} />Celeb
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" value="text" onChange={this.radioChange} />Text
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input className="fileInput"
                        type="file"
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleImageChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                    <button className="submitButton"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Upload Image</button>
                </form>
                <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Input Image</h2>
                    {$imagePreview}                
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Output Image</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.celebData()}
                    <h4>Description :-</h4>
                </div>

        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Image;
```

below is the package.json code

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.2",
    "antd": "^3.23.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and display axios is not defined error in console
[axios error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdVY0.png)

Comment: Did you install axios? npm install axios --save

Comment: {isFilePath: "false", fileByte: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAABsF…rZ3C6fVAxXUO6xKfhfwCZUMclW8cSAAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="} file byte display the base64 image encoding i.E byte data

Comment: can you post package.json code?

Comment: im adding code in above post

Comment: you said axios is installed! just try restarting the server or uninstall axios and install it again!

Comment: doing also that but still getting the issue and upload corresponding image for that you can see the image also

Answer (score 1):

First you can install this package,

```
npm i axios --save
```

then run your app again.

Comment: im alreday insall axios